# equal numpy array solve in python np.array([0,4,2])*x==np.array([0,8,4])?

Tags: numpy, multiplication, equality, solver

Given two arrays, A and B:

```
A=np.array([0,4,2])
B=np.array([0,8,4])
```

I want to know if I can multiply A by a scalar (x) and get B (A*x==B?) and if that is the case I want to know the value of the scalar (in this case 2). I have searched and tried the solve function without luck

Answer (score 0):

If `A*x = B`, then `x = B/A` for `A ≠ 0`.

You can do this:

```
A=np.array([0,4,2])
B=np.array([0,8,4])

# remove indices where A is null
m = A!=0

# ensure B values are null where A value are null
assert np.allclose(B[~m], 0)

# compute B/A
out = B[m]/A[m]

# ensure all values are (almost) equal
assert np.allclose(out-out[0], 0)

# print result
print(out[0])
```

output: `2.0`

Comment: If `A` has a value of 0 where `B` does not, this method will then give an incorrect value where it should fail.

Comment: @duckboycool fair enough. You can easily check that `B[~m]` values are close to 0 though.

Comment: @Helena did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes :) Don't know why my comment is missing but yes. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Helena which comment?